# NuGet API for unlisted / deprecated package

Tags: nuget

Is there by NuGet API call to find whether a certain package is set

1. unlisted
2. deprecated

And in case of unlisted/ deprecated to get the reason or suggestion references?

Answer (score 1):

Oh sorry, I see it seems to be quite easy - just call the

[https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/{package-id}/index.json](https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/%7Bpackage-id%7D/index.json)

and then search for

1. items.items.listed (and its boolean val)
2. items.items.deprecation and its properties e.g. alternatePackage

example:
https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/dotnet-tool-outdated/index.json